# What dependency needs to be added to avoid java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/internal/guava/Sets?

Tags: java, maven, jersey

Any idea what maven dependency(also the version) to add in pom.xml for this error? I'm using an external jar so not sure what to add exactly for this.

Comment: You're probably looking for a version of Jersey-common https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common If you give some more details (is it a java or android app), it'd be easier to help.

Comment: Hi Hakan, it's a java application. It's just imported for creating a set but since it's in a jar I cannot change it. I think it's jersey not guava.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the `jersey-common` library. You can try referencing the latest version up to date:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

If it fails, you can try decreasing version number from [this list](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common).

Comment: Good to hear that. Can you please mark my answer as correct and maybe upvote for it. :-)